# Configuring Apache on server b.example.com to allow secure resources on b.example.com to be requested from example.com without warnings?

Tags: apache, ssl, apache2, subdomain, ssl-certificate

I have server A, which host our main site on www.example.com; we have an SSL certificate that covers *.example.com.

On the secure part of our site, we wish to make a request to a web-service we have written and  host on a separate machine/IP, server B. The web-service has been allocated sub.example.com, so our SSL certificate covers that.

What do we need to do in terms of configuring Apache on server B? As I understand it, aside from the virtual section listening on 443, we also need to configure:

```
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
```

I guess my question is — do we have to use our certificate and key from server A here, or can we just create a self-signed on, perhaps specifying sub.example.com when creating the certificate?

I should add — the aim of this is to avoid browser security warnings, and the like, when visitors enter the secure part of example.com on server A. . .

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid warnings, all requests made from a page served from a page obtained using an `https://` URL should be made using HTTPS too.

Both servers should be configured with certificates that are valid for the host names they want to serve.

If your web-service (on server B) isn't directly used by server A's users, that is, if the browser talks to server A, then server A talks to server B in the background (effectively server A is a client there), but the browser never makes any request to server B, you can use a self-signed certificate on server B without any problem, provided you configure your application running on server A to trust that certificate (this depends entirely on how this application is implemented).

If the user's browser is expected to make connections to both server A and server B (perhaps via XHR or to load extra content such as images or scripts), you should make sure that both servers use certificates that be trusted by the browser. In this case, you would have to use your wildcard certificate + private key on both (or at least certificates + priv. keys valid on each.)

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer.

To clarify — we have situation (2). The browser makes AJAX requests to the web-service on server B to load extra content. Could you explain the private key part a little more? Would it be possible to create our own private key for Server B (I assume it would be some sort of sub-key to the original private key on server A)?

Comment: Usually, the expression "installing a certificate" on a server implies installing its corresponding private key too. Here since you're using a wildcard certificate, the same certificate + private key can be used on the two servers. There's only one private key for that certificate though, so it will need to be copied and installed on the two servers. If you want to use a different private key, you'd also need a different certificate (so you'd need to apply for it separately). (It's generally better practice and one of the reason wildcard certs are discouraged.)

Comment: What happens if we apply for a specific sub.example.com cert but also have a wildcard cert running on *.example.com? Are there any foreseen problems? Do we have to purchase from same CA authority? I'd like to not have multiple copies of a private key on different servers for security reasons, so a separate cert would be best.

Comment: @Edwardr, what matters is that the client sees a certificate that it trusts and that is valid for that machine. It's fine to have `sub.example.com` on one and `*.example.com` on another (e.g. for `www.example.com`). They don't have to be from the same CA. By the way, regarding the AJAX service, you may run into issues regarding same-origin policy, but that's not specific to HTTPS.